# Average rating from SQL database survey data

Tags: mysql, database

I've been trying to return the average rating of an organizer based on ratings from a table with survey data (targetting one column).

```
Table: Workshops
Cols: id[pk] | title | description | survey_id[fk] | organizer_id[fk] 

Table: Organizers
Cols: organizer_id[pk] | organizer_name | organizer_email | organizer_rating

Table: Surveys
Cols: survey_id[pk] | survey_desc | survey
```

And the table with user responses is as follows:

```
Table: SurveyUserResponse
Cols: s_u_r_id[pk] | username | survey_id[fk] | answer_1 | answer_2 | answer_3
```

Answer 3 is essentially the speaker's rating. I attempted to select the average rating on answer 3 and joining it with workshops based on organizer ID but it does not return the right average for an organizer.

This has got me quite stumped and I am unsure how to get the rating into the organizer rating column of the ratings table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Thank you for the advice Eduard. As per your suggestion, this is an example record:

```
Table: Workshops
id | title | description | survey_id | organizer_id
---------------------------------------------------
1  | ws01  | on pottery  | 1         | 1

Table: Organizers
organizer_id | organizer_name | organizer_email | organizer_rating
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1            | Ray Dion       | r.dion@ws01.com | <trying to get result here>

Table : Surveys
survey_id | survey_desc | survey
---------------------------------
1         | ws01 survey | test

Table: SurveyUserResponse
s_u_r_id | username  | survey_id | answer_1 | answer_2 | answer_3
-----------------------------------------------------------------
114      |  joe21331 | 1         | 4        | 5        | 3
```

This is what I came up with so far just to test if a proper data set is returned:

```
 SELECT     Organizers.organizer_id, Organizers.organizer_name,
       AVG(survey_user_response.answer_value_3) AS organizer_rating
 FROM Organizers, survey_user_response
 INNER JOIN Workshops organizer_id
 ON Workshops.organizer_id = Organizers.organizer_id
 ORDER BY organizer_rating DESC
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server or really both?

Comment: I was wondering for both but primarily MySQL.

Comment: Some sample data would really help and also, just for good practice, provide the column's datatypes. If you add your attempts then you will be even one step closer to getting an answer from all of these good people here, including me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL:

```
SELECT  o.*,
        AVG(answer_3)
FROM    surveyUserResponse sur
JOIN    workshops w
USING   (survey_id)
JOIN    organizers o
USING   (organizer_id)
GROUP BY
        organizer_id
```

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    organizers o
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  AVG(answer_3)
        FROM    workshops w
        JOIN    surveyUserResponse sur
        ON      sur.survey_id = w.survey_id
        WHERE   w.organizer_id = o.organizer_id
        ) q (rating)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was exactly what I needed. I was overcomplicating the process when it was in fact simpler with the USING clause together with joining multiple tables.